# If I approve a malicious contract with 1 address does it compromise other addresses derived from the same private key?

Tags: nft, private-key, hardware-wallets

I am a little bit worried about NFT scams.

My NFT wallet address is derived from the same private key that my ETH cold storage address. I am using a Ledger Hardware wallet.

My question is:
If I approve a malicious contract with my NFT account (address) and it gets drained/hacked does it mean that my other address that’s derived from the same private key is also compromised?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Given just an address you cannot get the public key.

Given just the public key, it's practically impossible to get the private key.

If you just approved a contract to handle/manage your NFTs, that's all they can do, handle/manage/**steal** your NFTs, but they cannot drain the ether balance of your address if they don't have the private key or trick you into signing a transaction that says so (trick you to sign a transaction that actually drains your ether in that address), but the other addresses derived from the same private key will not be compromised.